# How to preserve case of json key inside glue table which use serde?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, aws-glue, hive-serde

I have created a glue table which converts the the json to parquet files .In one of the column which is defined as **Map<String,String>** having a nested json .I see the nested json key is getting converted to lowercase always irrespective of input .

For example :

```
 "payload": {
          "cpr_Rate": "10",
          "type":"cpr"
        }
```

When I read the parquet file I see `cpr_Rate` gets converted to `cpr_rate` all lower case .I am using `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe`. I tried using `case.insensitive" = "FALSE"` property too  but it did not work either .I am open to change any other type of serde too if that preserve the case of my input .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` replace `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe`